# Why upper sum of Thomae function $\le 2\delta N+(1/m)(1-2\delta N)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions

[image]

I have problem with qn 36(iii). First I don't know what it meant by "where points are suppressed in the subdivision where there is overlap". I had already proved the question with alternative way by making difference of lower and upper integral of $f$ be smaller than null sequence but this time I am struggling hard. Here is the answer.

[image]

I already knew I need to choose something for $\delta$ but I struggled when I saw upper sum $$\le 2\delta N+(1/m)(1-2\delta N)$$. I thought upper function might be defined as $$1 \cdot 2\delta N+0 $$ Since upper function is defined as $S(x)=1$ when $c_i-\delta<x<c_i+\delta$ since Upper sum is defined as summation of change of x times the supremum of that change and this time supremum is 1 so it should be multiplied by $2\delta N$ because $\sum^{N}_{i=0} -(c_i-\delta)+c_i+\delta=2 N\delta$ and there is plus 0 because of $S(x)=1/m$ so area is 0. So shouldn't it be upper sum$< 2\delta N+(1/m)(1-2\delta N)$ when will it be equal? Why is there $+(1/m)(1-2\delta N)$ is there any reason for that.And what did it mean by "where points are suppressed in the subdivision where there is overlap".So Overlap what? Overlap with interval or sum or overlap with itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is to choose a partition of $[0,1]$ such that the points $c_1,\dots,c_N$ (where $f$ is "far" from step function being used for the lower sum) are included in subintervals of length $2\delta$. Elsewhere you just don't care about how fine the partition is, because $f$ is "close" to the step function being used for the lower sum.

The minor technical issue that arises when you try to write this down naively is that you don't have a guarantee that $c_n+\delta<c_{n+1}-\delta$, which means that some of the intervals $(c_n-\delta,c_n+\delta)$ might overlap with each other. But that doesn't actually hurt anything: you can still take the set of points in the partition to be $\{ 0 \} \cup \{ c_n -\delta : n=1,\dots,N \} \cup \{ c_n+\delta : n=1,\dots,N \} \cup \{ 1 \}$. The subinterval containing $c_n$ will still be of length at most $2\delta$. It's just that the partition elements might not be in order when listed as $0,c_1-\delta,c_1+\delta,\dots,c_N-\delta,c_N+\delta,1$.

Anyway, what happens now is that the upper sum has two parts: first there is the part on the subintervals containing the $c_n$. Here they just use the crude bound $f(x) \leq 1$ (which holds everywhere, of course), and they intend to make the resulting contribution small by choosing $\delta$ to be so small that $\delta N$ is also small. Second there is the part located elsewhere. Here they use the bound $f(x) \leq 1/m$, which makes the rest small. The subtraction of $2\delta N$ inside the parentheses is valid but not really necessary; you could just as easily have said that the upper sum is less than $2\delta N + 1/m$.

The use of nonstrict inequalities when strict inequalities hold is a common thing in analysis, it's really just a matter of laziness (if a nonstrict inequality will do the job that you need, then you can just write that down and not have to worry about the possibility that maybe the strict version doesn't hold). That said, as they say, if you choose $\delta$ small enough that $0<c_1-\delta<c_1+\delta<\dots<c_N-\delta<c_N+\delta<1$, then their formula for the upper sum becomes exact.

Comment: they used $f(x)>1/m$ not $f(x)\le1/m$

Comment: @2Balls1Bat No, away from $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_N$ they are using the bound $f(x) \leq 1/m$, since $f(x)$ is only $>1/m$ at those points.

Comment: Oh I understand it now. That is because of upper sum's definition.

Comment: @2Balls1Bat Overall the goal is to say that the upper sum can be made arbitrarily small, because the lower sum is identically zero. The method is to split the interval into a "good" set, which here is $\{ x : f(x) \leq 1/m \}$, and a "bad" set, which here is $\{ x : f(x) > 1/m \}$.  The contribution to the upper sum from the good set can be bounded by a constant times $1/m$, which is good as long as you can send $m \to \infty$ without spoiling your calculation on the bad set.

Comment: (Cont.) The contribution to the upper sum from the bad set can be bounded by the size of the bad set, since $f(x) \leq 1$ everywhere.